# Is there such a thing as XML 2.0?

Tags: xml

I'm trying to build a .swc containing a .xml config file into Flash Builder, but I keep getting an error saying that there is an XML version mismatch on my .xml config file; it specifies a 2.0 xml.

I've tried on my own specifying a version 2.0 in the opening tag of the .xml file such as:

`<?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

but that didn't work.

I also googled xml 2.0 and wikipedia says that there is no official release of xml 2.0, though a few sites mention the above opening tags as xml 2.0. So is there xml 2.0 out there and if so, how do I use it?

Comment: xml 2.0 is purported to be 1.0 - DTD. Most people use that subset anywy already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is not. There are currently two versions of XML: v1.0 and v1.1. The v1.0 Standard is currently available in the Fifth Edition, the v1.1 Standard in the Second Edition.

The [W3C recommends](http://www.w3.org/XML/Core/) the use of v1.0, as long as you dont need [the features of v1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/).

All to be read [here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Markup_Language) and [here on the W3C page](http://www.w3.org/XML/Core/).

Comment: Thanks x3ro, very much appreciated.