# XML version 1.1 in Oracle 11g

Tags: xml, oracle, encryption, oracle11g

I ran into a interesting problem - one of my colleagues wrote nice piece of code for encrypting/decrypting passwords and he is using this procedure to encrypt passwords for XML messages.

When building XML, he does not really build XMLTYPE but mere CLOB. Problem is in his encrypting procedure he is not ommiting **Control characters**( U+0000 to U+001F ).

When somebody wants to process this CLOB as XML we get an error. 
I did some search and found that maybe using XML version=1.1 will help. Although I am not able to manage the conversion - when I add `version="1.1"`
to the xml it throws me exception `LPX-00235:invalid XML version, mst be 1.0 or 2.0`

Question is - how to force XML to be version 1.1 in Oracle DB?

Thanks for suggestions,

Mike

Comment: Yep, happens to smarter people :D

Comment: A strange error message, since [there isn't an XML 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692111/is-there-such-a-thing-as-xml-2-0), AFAIK. Could your colleague not just store this data base64-encoded instead?

Comment: I know strange. Anyways, thanks for the BASE64-encode tip, we will use this.